Removing true holes in a doughnut polygon
I want to create small cuts to open the holes in a shapefile, while the cuts should be contiguous without affecting the main shape and size of the polygons. The goal is not to have any true holes in a polygon to avoid issues when importing the shapefiles into other software that does not understand true holes in the polygon and fills and overlap any polygons that may be in the hole. While I can do this manually on ArcMap and cut open each feature, this will take forever for huge amount of catchments.
Before

After


Some software will mark such polygon having geometry error (QGIS flag it as "self contact" error) so made sure that wont be blocking in your intended use

You'd be better off using software that isn't braindead, and understands that holes are  natural part of the polygon experience. You can't keep the same area and make valid polygons, and making invalid polygons will cause unpredictable results from correctly functioning software.

You had a tag for QGIS but do not mention it in your question body so  have removed it.

If you still want to do this after considering the comments by J.R and Vince you are going to have to use arcpy to read and write geometries.
For the example in the read geometries link the polygon with the hole would need to be rewritten as shown here:
Feature 2:
Part 0:
9.0 11.0
9.0 8.0
6.0 8.0
6.0 11.0
9.0 11.0
Interior Ring:
7.0 10.0
7.0 9.0
8.0 9.0
8.0 10.0
7.0 10.0


Feature 2:
Part 0:
9.0 11.0
9.0 8.0
6.0 8.0
6.0 11.0
7.0 10.0
7.0 9.0
8.0 9.0
8.0 10.0
7.0 10.0
6.0 11.0
9.0 11.0

Start coding and report back any problems you might encounter.
